# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

Estoy usando XAMPP y sin embargo no puedo lanzar el servidor **Apache**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he intentado cambiando los puertos y sigue sin funcionar.

```
[Sun Feb 14 16:57:17.914171 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 2968:tid 708] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Feb 14 16:57:18.148474 2021] [core:warn] [pid 2968:tid 708] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sun Feb 14 16:57:18.179713 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 2968:tid 708] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Feb 14 16:57:18.179713 2021] [:emerg] [pid 2968:tid 708] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

Instale **Wamp Server** para hacer una prueba y funciono sin problemas. Pero necesito **XAMPP** por una base de datos que tengo en phpmyadmin.

Comment: WAMP también incluye MySQL, no? WAMP es un acrónimo de Windows Apache MySQL PHP

Comment: Lo que necesitas mas bien es una interfaz para administrar tu BD, porque XAMPP ya integra por defecto phpmyadmin, pero eso no quiere decir que solamente con phpmyadmin podras acceder a tu BD ya que ambas traen consigo MySQL

Comment: Ahora de programas/herramientas para administrar BDs hay muchas como phpmyadmin, navicat, mysql workbench, etc

Comment: He intentando acceder a las bases de datos con distintos manejadores y/o herramientas y ninguna me permite ver las bases de datos que tengo creadas desde xampp. Al igual que tengo un sistema que administra una base de datos y al tratar de acceder desde wamp no accede, como si no existiera conexión a la base de datos.